# Java time problems

Tags: java, date, time

I have a problem of inconsistency with time objects

```
Time time1 =  new Time(72000000); //21:00
Time time2 = new Time(new Date().getTime()); //before 21 pm

time2.before(time1);
```

The last line returns always false, why?

Comment: Java Time is about the amount of ms since January 1, 1970.

Comment: This is one of those questions that always gets upvoted but are answered straight in the API.

Comment: The answers offered give a good explanation of whats happening. I'd recommend using the JodaTime (http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if you can as the API for time and Date manipulation is a lot nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not doing what you think it's supposed to do!

```
Time time1 =  new Time(72000000);
```

See this:

> ```
> Time
>
> public Time(long time)
>
> Constructs a Time object using a milliseconds time value.
>
> Parameters:
>     time - milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT; a negative number is milliseconds before January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
> ```

Now, hopefully you understand...

Comment: The other guy answered it first

Answer (score 2):

Time:

*A thin wrapper around the java.util.Date class that allows the JDBC API to identify this as an SQL TIME value. The Time class adds formatting and parsing operations to support the JDBC escape syntax for time values.
The date components should be set to the "zero epoch" value of January 1, 1970 and should not be accessed.*

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html

Basically you're comparing 21:00 at the first of january 1970 to your current date at some point in the day. Obviously the former time happens earlier and is 'smaller'.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify otherwise, I assume that the `Time` object is `java.sql.Time`.

This object uses a superclass of `java.util.Date` so it is actually a full date object.  For the purposes of JDBC (SQL) it only concerns itself with the time portion of the date.

This:

```
Time time1 =  new Time(72000000);
```

...creates an object that represents 1-January-1970 21:00 hours.  It will always be before any current time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that time1 is 14:00 . Run the below code snippet.

```
 Time time1 =  new Time(72000000); //21:00
 System.out.println(time1); //prints 14:00
 System.out.println(new Date());
 Time time2 = new Time(new Date().getTime()); //before 21 pm
```